# Расчет самого выгодного кредита в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Нужно написать код для того, чтобы он высчитывал наиболее выгодный кредит. Я в питоне новичок и получилась вот такая штука:

```
print ('Введите "start" для начала расчета: ')
n = input ()
if n == 'start':
    for i in 'start':
        money = input ('Сумма денег: ')
        money = int (money)

        percent = input ('Процент кредита: ')
        percent = int (percent)

        years = input ('Насколько лет берется кредит: ')
        years = float (years)

        percent1 = percent / 100
        month_pay = (money * percent1 * (1 + percent1) ** years) / (12 * ((1 + percent1) ** years
                                                                          - 1))
        print ('Месячный платеж: %.f' % month_pay)

        t_sum = month_pay * years * 12
        credit_sum = '%.f%%' % ((t_sum / money) * 100)
        print ('Сумма за весь период: %.f' % t_sum)
        print ('Это составит', credit_sum, 'от первоначальной суммы')

        credit_min = credit_sum
        if credit_sum < credit_min:
            credit_min = credit_sum
        print ('\n' + 'Введите "stop" для окончания расчета или что угодно для продолжения: ')
        n = input ()
        if n == 'stop':
            break
    print ('\n' + 'Самый выгодный процент выплаты по кредиту будет: ' + credit_min,
           '\n\n' + 'Это был кредит на следующих условиях:',
           '\n' + 'Сумма денег:', int (money),
           '\n' + 'Процент кредита:', '%.f%%' % percent,
           '\n' + 'Насколько лет берется кредит:', int (years),
           '\n' + 'Месячный платеж:', '%.f' % month_pay,
           '\n' + 'Сумма за весь период:', '%.f' % t_sum)
```

Проблема в том, что я попытался встроить расчет кредита в цикл, чтобы в итоге выдавался самый выгодный кредит на основе процента от первоначальной суммы, который придется отдать. Как раз выдача самого выгодного и не работает, я совершенно не понимаю, почему, может кто помочь?

Comment: А Вы точно понимаете что делает конструкция `for i in 'start'` ?

Comment: Нет, очень слабо, я же говорю, фактически новичок и толком не смог разобраться, как это работает.

Comment: Ну-у-у, в переводе с питоньего на человечий это будет примерно: Для каждой буквы в слове `start` выполнить: тут_ваш_код. Наверно это не совсем то, что Вы хотели :) Это только то, что с самого начала в глаза бросилось, там у Вас ещё много непонятных для меня вещей - например, смысл этого условия `if credit_sum < credit_min` , какое-то очень сильное колдунство...

Comment: Я его взял в свое время из этого кода: <pre> <code> n = int(input())
n_max = n
while n != 0:
    if n > n_max:
        n_max = n
    n = int(input())
print(n_max)

Comment: А еще не понимаю, как тут код вставить внутри ответа

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под высказыванием `наиболее выгодный кредит`? Мне так кажется, что это кредит с наименьшей ставкой. Может вы хотите сранить какой метод начисления процентной ставки выгоднее, аннуитетный или  дифференцированный? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Основная идея, чтобы процент, сколько надо заплатить по итогу банку, был наименьший.

Comment: Если вы не упоминаете о методах начисления процентной ставки, то чем меньше процентная ставка, тем меньше переплата по кредиту.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не проверял ваш код для вычислений, предполагая, что он правилен.

После исправления ошибок в вашем коде я сделал только минимальные изменения в вашем коде, чтобы он правильно работал:

```
credit_min = float('inf')     # бесконечно

while True:
    print()
    money = input ('Сумма денег (0 для окончения): ')
    money = int (money)
    if not money:
        break;

    percent = input ('Процент кредита: ')
    percent = int (percent)

    years = input ('Насколько лет берется кредит: ')
    years = float (years)

    percent1 = percent / 100
    month_pay = (money * percent1 * (1 + percent1) ** years) / (12 * ((1 + percent1) ** years
                                                                      - 1))
    print ('Месячный платеж: %.f' % month_pay)

    t_sum = month_pay * years * 12
    credit_sum = (t_sum / money) * 100
    credit_sum_str = '%.f%%' % credit_sum
    print ('Сумма за весь период: %.f' % t_sum)
    print ('Это составит', credit_sum_str, 'от первоначальной суммы')

    if credit_sum < credit_min:
        credit_min = credit_sum
        money_result = money
        percent_result = percent
        years_result = years
        month_pay_result = month_pay
        t_sum_result = t_sum

if credit_min < float('inf'):
    print ('\n' + 'Самый выгодный процент выплаты по кредиту будет: ' + str(credit_min),
           '\n\n' + 'Это был кредит на следующих условиях:',
           '\n' + 'Сумма денег:', str(money_result),
           '\n' + 'Процент кредита:', '%.f%%' % percent_result,
           '\n' + 'Насколько лет берется кредит:', years_result,
           '\n' + 'Месячный платеж:', '%.f' % month_pay_result,
           '\n' + 'Сумма за весь период:', '%.f' % t_sum_result)
```

Я отбросил ненужное *'Введите "start" для начала расчета: '* и вместо введения `stop` программа окончится после введения `0` для суммы денег:

```
money = input ('Сумма денег (0 для окончения): ')
```

Comment: @MichaelStepanov, не стоит. Пожалуйста, пометите мой ответ «принятым» (клик на галочку у него) и / или голосуйте за него, если он полезным для вас. (См. [Добро пожаловать на сайт «Stack Overflow на русском»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)).